# How to find active tag formats using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation with sample code as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <h1>The header</h1>
      <div>
        matter ia always matter matter ia <strong>bold matter</strong> matter matter <em>italics matter</em>matter ia <em><strong>bold italics matter</strong></em>lways matter
      </div>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to retrieve the specific tags like `body->p->div->em->strong` when I click on `"bold italics matter"` using jQuery. Is there any standard method to retrieve as per the click event?

Comment: use parents() in jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to get the tag name of the element which is clicked, then you can use:

```
$('*').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log($(this).prop('tagName'));    
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2WZF8/1/)**

Comment: It works, you need to open the browser console to see the result. Nevermind here is the `alert` version: http://jsfiddle.net/2WZF8/2/

Comment: Thanks for fast reply man.
But I want to display all the parent tags ie body->p->div->em->strong

Comment: I want to create a WYSIWYG editor with a status bar.
When the user click on some text the status bar shows the parent tags with my code as I posted before. But when the user moves cursor through keyboard its not working. any help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you are trying to accomplish. If you are trying to retrieve the tag itself that the text is contained in, i would recommend that you put a `<span>` tag in around the the text in question and do an `onclick="function()"` or simply put the onclick right on the `<strong>` tag.

As far the the JQuery/Javascript goes, if you want to retrieve the content, it looks like

```
var foo = document.getElementById.innerHTMl("id");
```

However, this requires you to have an id in your tags which is probably the best, if not 
'standard' method of retrieving the content that is within the tag.

After reading your comments, i am editing this post:
The best way to get the parent elements is to use the JQUery `.parent()` function. I'd imagine that you would just recursively state something like this:

```
var foo = $("nameofelement").parent();
```

I hope this is more of what your looking for.

Comment: Actually I want the full tracing of parent TAGs backwards when I click some tag contents

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributing everybody. At last I made it myself with the following code.

```
$(document.body).click(function(e){
    var Tags=[], Target=e.target, stat_msg="";

    Tags.push(Target.tagName);
    while($(Target).parent().get(0).tagName!=="BODY")
    {
        Tags.push($(Target).parent().get(0).tagName);
        Target=$(Target).parent();
    }
    Tags.push("BODY");

    for(i=Tags.length;i>0;i--)
        stat_msg=stat_msg+Tags[i-1]+" ";

    alert(stat_msg);
});
```